# Adjusting PC's speaker output in realtime

Tags: software, speakers

Is there any software available that allows me alter my PC's speaker output in realtime?

I'd like to be able to change pitch. I'm used to editing my speakers properties in the enhancements tab but I'd like something more powerful and quicker to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using routing software such as jack or soundflower(os x only), you can intercept audio from one program and run it into another one.  Perhaps this will meet your need.

http://jackaudio.org/